# IBM MQ : Connection to host 'localhost/127.0.0.1:1414' rejected

Tags: java, spring-boot, openshift, ibm-mq

My spring-boot application runs in openshift and connects to IBM MQ.
The JMS configuration is defined in application.yaml. But when the spring-boot application starts, the below exception occurs.  What could be the cause of this exception ?

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').
         at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.4.0.jar:9.2.4.0 - p924-L211104]
         ... 96 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'localhost(1414)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'localhost/127.0.0.1:1414' rejected. [1=java.net.ConnectException[Connection refused (Connection refused)],3=localhost/127.0.0.1:1414,4=TCP,5=Socket.connect]],3=localhost(1414),4=,5=RemoteTCPConnection.bindAndConnectSocket]
         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP$Connector.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:13610) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.4.0.jar:9.2.4.0 - p924-L211104]
         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP$Connector.access$100(RemoteFAP.java:13150) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.4.0.jar:9.2.4.0 - p924-L211104]
         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1449) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.4.0.jar:9.2.4.0 - p924-L211104]
         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1390) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.4.0.jar:9.2.4.0 - p924-L211104]
         at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:377) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.4.0.jar:9.2.4.0 - p924-L211104]
         at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:562) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.4.0.jar:9.2.4.0 - p924-L211104]
         at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:391) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.4.0.jar:9.2.4.0 - p924-L211104]
         ... 95 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'localhost/127.0.0.1:1414' rejected. [1=java.net.ConnectException[Connection refused (Connection refused)],3=localhost/127.0.0.1:1414,4=TCP,5=Socket.connect]
         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.bindAndConnectSocket(RemoteTCPConnection.java:932) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.4.0.jar:9.2.4.0 - p924-L211104]
         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1419) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.4.0.jar:9.2.4.0 - p924-L211104]
         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:1012) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.4.0.jar:9.2.4.0 - p924-L211104]
         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:688) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.4.0.jar:9.2.4.0 - p924-L211104]
         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:282) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.4.0.jar:9.2.4.0 - p924-L211104]
         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:181) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.4.0.jar:9.2.4.0 - p924-L211104]
         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:127) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.4.0.jar:9.2.4.0 - p924-L211104]
         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP$Connector.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:13350) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.4.0.jar:9.2.4.0 - p924-L211104]
         ... 101 common frames omitted




spring:
  environment: DEV
  jms:
    wmq:
      host: mq.cloud-mq.svc.cluster.local
      port: 1414
      queue-manager:
      channel: DEV.APP.SVRCONN
```

Comment: Can you telnet to the same host and port?

Comment: Do you have an MQ TCP Listener running on your queue manager?

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection to host 'localhost/127.0.0.1:1414' rejected
```

Your MQ server is deployed on host`localhost`, ie in the same pod as you app ???

Check where you define the IBM MQ server host in your config, it is probably the source of the error

Comment: The MQ server running on a different project in openshift

Answer (score 0):

That Spring is trying to connect to `localhost(1414)` implies that the configuration in `application.yaml` isn't quite correct.

It is not clear if you are you making use of `mq-jms-spring-boot-starter` ( https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring ). If you are then you may be falling into a default trap, where default attributes are:

> The default attributes are
>
> ```
> ibm.mq.queueManager=QM1 
> ibm.mq.channel=DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN
> ibm.mq.connName=localhost(1414) 
> ibm.mq.user=admin
> ibm.mq.password=passw0rd
> ```

At least the last three will need to be set to valid values in line with your configuration.

You can find some more samples here - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/tree/master/Spring-JMS